# render div out of dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I created a dialog used jQuery UI dialog that had overflow scroll,
now I want to render one div element that one part is in dialog and another part is out of dialog,
How can I do this.

I used this code

```
.ui-dialog, .ui-dialog-content {
    overflow: visible !important
}
```

but I just want to that specific element render out of the dialog not all children.

Comment: "`... I just want to that specific element render out of the dialog not all children`"... Not possible.

Comment: @Teemu Agreed. He will simply need to write better CSS.

Comment: If `children` above means siblings of `"that specific element"`, you can position it with `fixed` (or `absolute`). This way it's taken out of the text-flow, and you can place it anywhere you want on the screen. Ofcourse all elements inside this "out-taken" element will follow their parent.